# getting null response after setting progard rule of retrofit2 and okhttp3 in my android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2, okhttp

i have successfully added progard rule but i am not getting data from server.
when i set  **debuggable false** , **minifyEnabled false** its working properly.

Progard setting
==================>>
[image]

gradle file
=============>>
[image]

Getting null response in my app SS below 
========================================>>
[image]

Answer (score 0):

keep your model class away from proguard obfuscation

`-keep public class your.package.to.models.** {*;}`

and also add your interface to your proguard rules

`-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}`